# SSMS import wizard trouble loading CSV date column with date and time with milliseconds

Tags: ssms

I have some large CSV files that I'm trying to import into a SQL Server table using ssms import wizard.  One of the columns is a date column formatted as yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss:xxx.  I've tried every date format in the source field that is offered to me, but it, at best, gives me the entire date with the milliseconds as .000 rather than the value that is in the .txt CSV file.

The only thing I can think of is that the input date has the milliseconds after a colon (:) rather that a period (.).  I could write a program that converts the colon to a period and then load it, but I did edit the file and changed the first six rows to period and that didn't seem to have any effect.

For the import I'm using "Flat File Source", under "Advanced", I select "DataType" for the column and have used every one of the following as the DataType.

database date [DT_DBDATE],  database time [DT_DBTIME], database time with precision [DT_DBTIME2],

database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP], database timestamp with precision [DT_DBTIMESTAMP2],

DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET] and even date [DT_DATE], decimal [DT_DECIMAL], file timestamp [DT_FILETIME]

The Destination is to SQL Server Native Client 11.0 to destination Type of datetime2 which is defined on the table as datetime2(7), not null.

With all these attempts I either get a "data would be truncated" error, or it would load with the milliseconds set to 000 rather than the value that is in the CSV file.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anyone that spent some time looking into this but I resolved my problem a different way.  Rather than convert my string datetime to database datetime, I just loaded it as a varchar column on my table.  I will only be using that datetime in the where clause of SELECT statements and never in date or time comparisons. It should work fine using a substring in my "where clause" when I need to select data.